# Foucsrite Scarlett 2i2 and Windows 7

Tags: recording

About a year ago I purchased the Focusrite Scarlett Studio which includes the 2i2 preamplifier.  I love the headphones, quite like the condenser microphone, but have not been able to get a sufficient volume level through the 2i2.  I have downloaded and installed the latest driver from Focusrite.  What else should I be doing?

Comment: "sufficient volume level " - in or out?

Comment: I use the 2i2 just for recording (with a microphone, not an instrument.)   I have used it with a variety of dynamic and condenser microphones  and the volume level is always very low.

Comment: Have you tried changing between line and instrument with the front switches? Is the 48v switch turned on when you are using the condenser?

Comment: if you digitally boost the signal after recording, what kind of noise do you have?  Sometimes the waveform looks small but it is a clean recording.